# Что означает разрешение repo для Github-токена?

Tags: github, travis

Я хочу подключить к своему проекту `Travis CI`. Один файл в репозитории мне нужно зашифровать *(чтобы его мог читать только `Travis`)*, для чего мне нужно сгенерировать Github-токен и передать его `Travis`.

Согласно [документации](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/github-oauth-scopes/#travis-ci-for-private-projects), токен должен содержать следующие разрешения:

- user:email
- read:org
- repo

Проблема заключается в том, что мой аккаунт в `Github` добавлен в приватные репозитории организации, в которой я работаю. И я не очень понимаю, что даёт разрешение `repo`. В [документации](https://docs.github.com/ru/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes) написано следующее:

> Grants full access to public and private repositories including read
> and write access to code, commit statuses, repository invitations,
> collaborators, deployment statuses, and repository webhooks. Note: In
> addition to repository related resources, the repo scope also grants
> access to manage organization-owned resources including projects,
> invitations, team memberships and webhooks. This scope also grants the
> ability to manage projects owned by users.

Значит ли это, что `Travis` получит возможность, например, коммитить в репозитории организации, в которой я работаю *(при условии, что я не являюсь владельцем организации, однако имею разрешения на внесение изменений в репозитории организации)*?
Если да, то можно ли как-то избежать передачи такого разрешения *(кроме создания отдельного аккаунта в `Github`)*?